# Upgrade with Python3.7.4 version in miniconda docker image

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, urllib3, miniconda

There is some security regression was discovered in python 3.7.3, which still allows an attacker to exploit.

An issue was discovered in urllib2 in Python. CRLF injection is possible if the attacker controls a url parameter, as demonstrated by the first argument to urllib.request.urlopen with \r\n (specifically in the query string after a ? character) followed by an HTTP header or a Redis command.

Below are the refrences for the issue:

```
[https://bugs.python.org/issue30458][1]
[https://bugs.python.org/issue33529][1]
[https://bugs.python.org/issue35755][1]
https://bugs.python.org/issue35907
https://bugs.python.org/issue36742
https://bugs.python.org/issue37463
```

The solution is to use Python 3.7.4 , which is released 9th of july 2019. But conda distribution is not released yet for python 3.7.4.

Now the question is:- Is there any way to upgrade python with python-3.7.4 in miniconda docker image container?

Docker file is : -

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.6.14
```

I tried to put upgrade python command in docker file but it fails as Python 3.7.4 is not available in conda distribution

```
repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
```

Comment: Please provide your current `dockerfile`

Comment: FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.6.14

I tried to put upgrade python command in docker file but it fails as Python 3.7.4 is not available in https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ or other conda distribution